# netbeans does not show errors in php environment

Tags: php, netbeans

I work on Windows with Netbeans in php environment. But I noticed the netbeans does not show errors neither in file nor in Projects tab. It marks lack of semicolon error type only.

For example this line is not error by netbeans:

```
efewfwefwe;
```

Could you tell me why? What must I set to solution in netbeans?

thank you

Comment: Are you using lint?

Comment: No, I don't.use it

Comment: Duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211935/netbeans-does-not-show-error-messages

Comment: Yes, I tried this solution but disabling braces does not help to me :(

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183362/php-syntax-check-on-html-files-in-netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Please Try Downloading the PHP Bundle, for Netbeans Distribution.
There Might be something Similar in WAMP Setup

This Answer Might Help From LAMP:
[How to enable PHP support in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473109/how-to-enable-php-support-in-netbeans)

Comment: The PHP bundle is enabled :-|